# Eloquent find() with joins and eager loading

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I want to retrieve one record via the time-tested method of this URL:

```
public/api/laptop/1
```

hitting this route:

```
Route::get('laptop/{id}', 'LaptopController@getLaptop');
```

then this controller method:

```
$laptop = Laptop::find($id)->addJoins()->selectListCols()->with('earmarks', 'movements')->get();
return $laptop;
```

Problem is this doesn't work (it returns every record). To make it work I have to do this:

```
$laptop = Laptop::where('laptops.id', $id)->addJoins()->selectListCols()->with('earmarks', 'movements')->get();
return $laptop;
```

But I'm just wondering why `find()` doesn't work? earmarks and movements are Many-To-One models, by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`find()` is just a [shortcut for `where()->first()`](https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/5.3/Eloquent/Builder.php#L160) so it will return an object and [Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries) methods will not work with it:

```
User::find(1); // Will return User object with ID = 1.
```

That's why you need to use `where()`, which returns Query Builder object, so you can use `with()` and other builder methods to build your query.

Comment: Okay, thanks. Are there any downsides to using `where()` instead as above?

Comment: No, it's absolutely normal to use `where()` in this query.

Comment: Thanks again. So, am I right in thinking that `find()` would only be useful when you don't need to do joins or selects are anything more complex than retrieving one record?

Comment: @daninthemix, yes, usually you want to use `find()` for something simple like `User::find(1)`.